# Transfering messages from one AWS Queue to another

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-sqs

Hi Can we send messages from one Queue to another in bulk without polling them and sending back to another Queue one by one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had a similar problem recently.

What I did in the end was to configure the DLQ's dead letter queue to be the main queue, with MaximumReceives of 1.

I could then use the console to poll the DLQ. Once a message had been read by the console, it would be moved back to the original queue. This clearly doesn't scale well to thousands of messages, but worked to clear the small backlog I was dealing with.

Comment: Hmm mine was for higher volumes and I did it by directly processing them.

Answer (score 3):

There is no native feature for sending messages from one queue to another. In this case you might want to use the fan-out technique.

1. Create a SNS topic
2. Subscribe both queues to this topic
3. Whenever you post a message to the topic both queues receive the message

[image: SQS Fanout]

Have a look at this link; https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/SNS_Scenarios.html

Comment: My scenario is different. I want to push messages from dead-letter-queue to main queue. If I want to reprocess them. Is it possible between queues

Comment: Unfortunately there is not a native feature for that. You would have to implement the process your self. Will keep my answer as it can be helpful to other folks looking for a way to feed two queues at the same time.